# Load more posts with Ajax and masonry

Tags: ajax, masonry

I'm using this method to load more posts with Ajax:
http://www.problogdesign.com/wordpress/load-next-wordpress-posts-with-ajax/

I'm also using masonry for the posts layout.

Masonry works fine for the first set of posts, but not for the next set of posts that are appended after clicking load more posts.

How can I make masonry work after loading more posts?"

Comment: this is a javascript question, not really a WordPress question. I'm also sure this is explained in the masonry documentation.

Comment: I tried with the JS file, I didn't know where to go. The documentation of masonry to load more posts is different than the method I sent.